# javascript function within a function not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, anonymous-function

EDIT: new problem is that even though current_slide.showCurrentSlide(); function is inside the hidePrevSlide function, the showCurrentSLide code is executing before the animation in hidePrevSlide is finished.

I am trying to create a website where if you click an < li > then the < li > will get a class added to it. It will then slide the current visible screen up and hide it and then show the screen corresponding to the < li > (for example, if the < li > is 'home' then it will slide the current existing screen up and hide it and then it would should the '#homeSlide' screen). Here is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    hideItems(); //this function basically hides all the screens / slides.. The words 'screen' and 'slides' are interchangeable for the time being.

    $('#homeSlide').fadeIn(1000); //the default screen to be shown is the home screen
    $('#homeSlide').addClass('current'); //to signify that this is the current visible screen
    $('#home').addClass('clicked'); //#home is the <li>, so it adds the .clicked class to the <li>

    $('#sidebar ul a li').click(function(){ //loops through all <li>'s in the sidebar if an <li> is clicked
        var current_slide = $(this);
        $('#sidebar ul .clicked').removeClass('clicked'); // when an <li> is clicked, remove .clicked class from any other <li>'s
        current_slide.addClass('clicked'); // add .clicked class to the clicked <li> ($(this))

        hidePrevSlide(function(){
            alert('enter showing step');
            current_slide.showCurrentSlide();
        });
    });
});
```

and here is my hidePrevSlide function.

```
function hidePrevSlide(){
    var test = $('.current').attr('id'); 
    test = "#" + test; // surrounds the id with a # and the word 'Slide'. This is the id of the screen which should slideUp
    $(test).slideUp( function () {
        $(test).hide();
        $(test).removeClass('current');
    });
alert('finished hiding step. Should enter showing step now');
};
```

Now, when I run the code, it does say 'finished hiding step. Should enter showing step now' but it does not say 'enter showing step' so it doesnt enter the step which should be executed after the hidePrevSlide function is done. How come?

Comment: `hidePrevSlide` never calls the function that you're passing as an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hidePrevSlide` needs to call the callback function.

```
function hidePrevSlide(callback){
    var test = $('.current');
    test.slideUp( function () {
        test.hide();
        test.removeClass('current');
    });
    alert('finished hiding step. Should enter showing step now');
    callback();
};
```

I also removed the use of `$(test)`. If you have an element, there's no need to keep searching for it by ID.

Comment: wait, for callback(); what exactly am I supposed to put? Because putting callback(); didn't work, I also tried putting current_slide.showCurrentSlide(); in place of where you put callback(); but that also didn't work

Comment: Ah okay, I replace the argument callback with 'showCurrentSlide' without any '()' after it and then I called the function with the '()' where you called callback.. okay makes sense. However, for some reason it still shows the 'current slide' before even hiding the previous slide, any idea why? should it execute the callback function After hidePrevSlide is fully finished executing? Because it shows the 'current slide' before the previous slide is finished sliding up.

Comment: Animation is asynchronous. So anything that should wait until the animation is finished should be in the function that you pass to `test.slideUp`.

Comment: I don't understand why `callback()` didn't work. It should call the anonymous function that you passed to `hidePrevSlide()`.

Comment: You changed `function hidePrevSlide()` to `function hidePrevSlide(callback)`, didn't you?

Comment: Okay there we go, it worked. And yea I forgot to add the callback as a parameter, and hm okay I'll try putting the entire showCurrentSlide function inside the function that I pass to test.slideUp.
EDIT: but I did hidePrevSlide(function() { current_slide.showCurrentSlide(); }); so shouldn't that already make the entire showCurrentSlide function and all the code in the showCurrentSlide function wait till the animation of hidePrevSlide is finished?

Comment: Whether it waits depends on where you put `callback()`. If you put it inside the `slideUp` callback, it waits until the animation is finished. If you put it outside that, it runs right after you start the animation.

Comment: When you call a JS function that performs asynchronous actions, like animation or AJAX calls, the function returns immediately after it starts the action, it doesn't wait for it to finish.